# PointToScreen is unknown

Tags: c#, xaml, mouse-position

I want to locate two controls on the screen to dynamically create a "Line" between them (the Line is already in the XAML code and changing its Stroke will make it appear). I tried to catch the Tapped event of these controls and use the event's GetPosition(), but the line is not at the right place (the angle is correct but the line is too far).
Some posts suggested to use PointToScreen. But my Visual Studio do not know System.Windows.Forms. Why ?

Comment: `PointToScreen` is not applicable in your case. It is method from Winforms framework, but your applicatiion build with WPF.

Comment: You may use [Visual.PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok ! It's not the right framework. I understand now why this happens all the time. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
 public void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var myControl = (YourControlType)sender;                         
            var position = e.GetPosition(myControl);
            var controlPosition= myControl.PointToScreen(position);
        }
```

Comment: That's it, except I can't call PointToScreen since it doesn't exists. Perhaps a missing Assembly or something like that (I don't understand a thing in this "References" stuff)